# プロジェクトが依存しているがリポジトリには存在しないファイルについて

Tags: git, github

あるgradleプロジェクトを`git clone`して手元でビルドしようとしたところ、`local.properties`なるファイルが存在しないためビルドできませんでした。（設定ファイル内での使われ方を見る限り、bintrayのAPIキーなどが入っているファイルのようです。）

そこで、あるファイルの`local.properties`に関する記述をコメントアウトしたところ、一応ビルドすることが出来ました。そのため今回の場合は、変更したファイルを`git update-index --assume-unchanged`して開発を続けることが出来そうです。

質問ですが、一般的にはプロジェクトが依存していてかつリポジトリに存在しないファイルにどう対処すべきですか？また上に書いたような解決法は妥当なものでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

(ローカル)リポジトリのトップディレクトリに`.gitignore`ファイルを作成し、その中に管理を無視したいファイルを記述しておく方法があります。

参考：
[Androidアプリの.gitignore - Qiita](https://qiita.com/jumperson/items/fa66995fb68de2847ffd)

```
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```

プログラミング言語や使用するIDEに応じた`.gitignore`を自動生成する [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) というサービスもあります。